# Can one see the transactions in the stock market?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, stock-markets, historical-data

Is it possible to see the individual transactions in a certain exchange market (e.g. NYSE) for a certain stock (e.g. GOOG)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [NYSE](http://www.nyxdata.com/), as well as all other exchanges, provide historical trade data.

Most provide [historical data on clearing agents as well, which is the most resolution possible](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/26313/11865).

Third parties often collect data and provide it for cheaper prices, but the data cannot be guaranteed to be complete or accurate.

All trades can be exported in real time from a data feed; however, some minor exchanges will not provide clearing agent information until after the close to provide for more anonymous trading.  Major exchanges provide clearing agent information in their data feeds.

Interactive Brokers gives a transaction history limited by some time with the same data as above except possibly the clearing agent.

Comment: can i see the transaction live as they happen?

Comment: If you call your broker and subscribe to level 2 quotes, then you can see the order book and also watch orders being filled.

Comment: I have a funded account, and I get real time quotes - price wise. My question was whether or not I can see the transaction's stock quantity, price, and other info?

Comment: To add further information: TD Ameritrade does not require to fund an account if you open one with them. Once you open an account you can Opt-In for their Live Level-II Data for free. Then download their ThinkOrSwim platform and install it. There you can see the Level-II live data. There is no historical data though.